# Idiomatic type conversion in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm frequently coming across situations where I have to use multiple piped type conversions in the form of to_x functions in order to properly access/transform data.

E.g.

```
IO.puts Enum.dedup Enum.intersperse(System.argv |> to_string |> to_charlist, 32)
```

This seems overly verbose. Is this idiomatic or am I missing something fundamental here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand this is a contrived example, but if you need multiple type conversions you are likely doing it wrong. The option would be to pick proper types up and use them across the application.

Whether you still want to do many piped conversions, declare macros for them:

```
defmacro to_chars(arg) do
  quote bind_quoted: [arg: arg] do
    arg |> to_string |> to_charlist
  end
end
```

And use them:

```
IO.puts System.argv
        |> to_chars
        |> Enum.intersperse(32)
        |> Enum.dedup
```

Comment: Why use a macro here instead of a plain function?

Comment: @Dogbert to make it available in guards.

Comment: But neither `to_string` nor `to_charlist` are allowed in guards.

Comment: I have just implemented the guard `empty?` for arbitrary input and my mind automatically read is_ instead of to_, even despite those names differ. Here do functions perfectly suit, absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is just an example, but you should use the proper functions. In this specific example, you can do the following.

```
System.argv()
|> Enum.join(" ")
|> IO.puts()
```

This would prevent you from doing the conversion and still has the result you expect.

Comment: The example I used was intended to insert a space between every character in the first argument. Sorry if this wasn't clear.

Comment: Your example puts a space between every character in all arguments. I assumed you were trying to put a space between the arguments. My point still stands though, you generally do not need to do so many conversions. There are generally functions for doing what you are doing on the types you already have.